# "Simple" rational inequality - How does one deduce this?

Tags: inequality

I am a little puzzled by a past exam question. Part (a) is very easy and part (b) is easy too. However, according to the question, and the mark scheme, I should be able to deduce the answer to part (b) from my answer to part (a) without any further calculation. I am able to find the answer to part (b), but I have to draw some graphs and it is far from straight forward.

**Part (a) [6 marks]**

Find the set of values of $x$ for which
$$x+4>\frac{2}{x+3}$$
As I said: this is easy. Multiply both sides by $(x+3)^2$, take everything over to one side and then factorise. This gives $(x+2)(x+3)(x+5)>0$ and so $-5<x<-3$ or $x>-2$.

**Part (b) [1 mark]**

This is where it gets a little odd. The question says: Deduce the values of $x$ for which
$$x+4>\frac{2}{|x+3|}$$
According to the solutions, **part (b) should be blindingly obvious**. The answer is $x>-2$. However, I don't see how one can deduce this trivially. I drew the graph and got the right answer, but a 1 mark question means it is obvious and there is no need for calculation.

Adding a modulus usually makes a problem more difficult and adds solutions, e.g. $x-1>2 \iff x>3$, while $|x-1|>2 \iff x<-1 \ \ \text{or} \ \ x>3$.

Answer (score 3):

The right-hand-side of (b) is positive. This forces $x > -4$. On the other hand, if $-4 < x < -3$, the left-hand side is less than $1$ but the right-hand-side is greater than $1$. Thus $x > -3$.

This means $|x + 3| = x+3$ so the two inequalities (a) and (b) are the same. Since the solution to (a) is $-5 < x < -3$ **or** $x > -2$, you must have $x > -2$.

I don't know if it is blindingly obvious, but there you go.

Comment: I was able to come up with a similar argument using the graph. I think that this is worth more than one mark, and isn't the the method that the solutions expects. I'm beginning to think that the exam setter does not understand inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what they expected you to do. But notice that 
$$x+4>\frac{2}{|x+3|}\geq\frac{2}{x+3}$$

This means that any solution of part (b) is a solution of part (a) and that discarding solutions is enough. It is not difficult to get rid of the interval $(-5,-3)$, but I think some argument has to be written in the exam.

Answer (score -1):

You can see the result from the calc out of a). 
but not out of yours.

I multiply first $(x+3)$. Then you have 2 cases.

First case $x+3 < 0$ then you've got $(x+4)(x+3) < 2$ (you have to change the sign, because you multipy by a negative figure)
this case return the solution $−5<x<−3$

And the second case $x+3 \geq 0$ returns $x>−2.$

It IS quite obvious, that if you multiply by $|x+3|$ there is only the second case. So only the solution of the second case is correct.